# Make variable read-only after initialization in another function/constructor [C++]

Tags: c++, constants, readonly

I have a class in A.h file:

```
class A {
...
public:
    A();
...
private:
    bool t = false;
...
}
```

In the A.cpp file:

```
A::A() {
    ...
    t = true; <- after this point, have t be const or readonly
    ...
}
```

Is this possible? Or would I have to use a different value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it in this way.

However you can still do what you *want* to do (you can change the exact mechanism to suit your precise needs since you weren't quite clear):

```
class A {
...
public:
    A();
...
private:
    bool A::init_A_impl();

    const bool t_;
...
};

bool A::init_A_impl()
{
    bool t = false;

    ...
    t = true; <- after this point, have t be const or readonly
    ...
    return t;
}

A::A() : t_(init_A_impl())
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In-class initialization of members works in C++11:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
private:
    const bool t = false;
};
```

Before C++11, you'd use member initializer list:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : t(false) {}
private:
    const bool t;
};
```

But `const` data members are unusual thing. For one, they make your class non-assignable (if you rely on compiler generated assignment operator). Just have the member private and don't let the interface provide the means to change it.